# Why is it not possible to tell the compiler to override onClick

Tags: java, android

I am making an Android application, and I have some buttons.
I want to add some listeners to them, so I have implemented `android.view.View.OnClickListener`, and added listeners to the buttons.

However, at the `onClick` method, I can't add the `Override` annotation like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) { /* With Override */ }
```

But this works:

```
public void onClick(View view) { /* Without Override */ }
```

And if I try to log something in the latter onClick method, it works as intended.

I am using Eclipse, and it keeps telling me that I must override a superclass method.

Why can't I add the `Override` annotation to it if I'm overriding it?

I am using Ubuntu 11.4, if that matters. `java -version` returns:

`java version "1.6.0_24"`
`Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)`
`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)`

Here is the code:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button btnFoo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFoo);
        btnFoo.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    // @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.e("foo", "bar");
    }
}
```

PS. I'm using Sun JDK 1.6

**EDIT:**

I've found this applies to most of the methods I'm trying to use, e.g `public void run()` (from `Runnable`).

Comment: Why *can't* you add it? What is the problem if you do it?

Comment: As I wrote: *I am using Eclipse, and it keeps telling me that I must override a superclass method.*

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I understood you wrong.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context in terms of code because a couple of things can happen here like: 1. You are actually not using JDK6 or above. 2. You are actually not overriding a method. 3. You simply hit an eclipse bug. Note that 'Froyo' or older uses JDK5.

Comment: I have added some code. It would be strange to not be overriding any method since it would then "automagically" know which method to call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to change the java sdk version to 1.6 and will be fix it

Answer (score 2):

Because there is nothing to override, you're implementing an interface not subclassing from a super class which already has definition for that method.
It simply makes no sense.

Comment: Applying the @Override annotation with an interface should work with Java 1.6. It fulfils the same purpose, in terms of saying, "I'm trying to use the same signature as another method - please check that I'm doing it properly."

Comment: Looking back at an Android application I made earlier, I used the annotation as described in the question, so it is obviously possible as Jon explained.